# Documentum xCP 2.0 creating multiple objects

Tags: business-process-management, documentum, xcp2.x

I am using xCP Designer 2.0 and I'm trying to create multiple objects at once. Say I receive the number 20 as input and need to create 20 of these objects with an increasing integer attribute from 1-20.

Is it possible to achieve this with a stateless process? How exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least 2 options:

- write an custom Java code an execute in inside Call Java Service activity
- create specific process flow to achieve it

If you decide for first, you can check how to integrate your custom (Java) code to the xCPDesigner via self paced tutorial which you can download from [this](https://developer-content.emc.com/downloads/jive_attach_proxy.htm?ecnCommID=2013&ecnCommName=Documentum&ecnAttachmentName=xCP%202.1%20Self%20Paced%20Tutorial%20v1.1.pdf&ecnContainerURL=/docs/DOC-36561&reqURL=/servlet/JiveServlet/download/36561-5-90172/xCP%202.1%20Self%20Paced%20Tutorial%20v1.1.pdf) link. You find useful things on [this](https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-36561) link too.

If you choose second approach, do it this way:

Add process variable like here

[image]

Model a stateless process like on the picture

[image]

Define *loop_count++* activity like on the picture

[image]

Note that *loop_count++* activity is of type *Set Process Data*. 
Additionally, you need to set trigger tab on Join activity like in a picture:

[image]

You will know what to do in *Create* activity. ;)

EDIT: I just saw I overlooked you stated that you set 20 when initiating stateless process. Logic is the same, you just use *Substract* function in *loop_count++* activity (you can consider changing activity name too) :)